# PHP/XPath: find text node that "starts with" a particular string?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I need to know if a particular string exist in a particular node. For example, I need to know if "quick brown fox" exist in the, say, 3rd paragraph of an HTML DOM. I'm using PHP's DOMXPath. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

**Example source:**

```
$html = <<< HTML
<body>
    <p>the dead brown fox</p>
    <p>the slow brown fox</p>
    <p>the quick brown fox</p>
    <p>the crawling brown fox</p>
</body>
HTML;
```

**Code:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xp->evaluate('count(/body/p[3][contains(., "quick")])');
```

The XPath translates to *[count](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count) the 3rd p element below the body element that [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) a text node value of "quick"*. This will return 1 or 0 if the searched term exists anywhere within the node value.

If you need to know if the node value *starts with* a specific phrase, use the [starts-with function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) instead.

PHP's DOM extension supports XPath 1.0.

You can also do it without XPath through the regular API:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($html);
$thirdPara = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(2);
echo strpos($thirdPara->nodeValue, 'the quick') === 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

The [`getElementsByTagName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method finds, who would have thought, all elements by tag name. The [`item`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) call returns the third of those elements (zero-based). The [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function finds the position of first occurrence of a string. The result of the snippet above would be 1 again (or 0 if the node value does not start with 'the quick'.