# Find parent node on node content text

Tags: php, xpath

Hey, i'm trying to find out the parent-node of the nodes content text.

example:

```
<div>
    <h1>Node to find</h1>
    <p>another node</p>
</div>
```

All my code know is what the text in the node is and my script needs to find out in what node the text contains.

i have tried the following xpaths:

```
 1. //*[. = "'. $text .'"]
 2. //*[contains(., "'. $text .'")]
```

the first gives me a empty nodeList
the second gives me a lot of nodes, but it gives me all the parent containing the text, i want only the first parent.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/XPath: find text node that "starts with" a particular string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822469/php-xpath-find-text-node-that-starts-with-a-particular-string)

Comment: `//*[contains(., "'. $text .'")][1]` or, depending on what you need, `//*[contains(text(), "'. $text .'")]`

Comment: got what i need with the following: `//*[starts-with(., "'. $text .'")]`

Comment: Check my answer for two correct XPath expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the `"'. $text .'"` part of your answer... I guess that means some sample text, not an intended reference to a variable named text?

Anyway, when you use `contains(., "foo")` you are asking whether the current node's string value contains "foo". The current node's string value is the concatenation of all **descendant** text nodes' string values. That is why `//*[contains(., "foo")]` returns a list of nodes: it matches every ancestor of every text node containing "foo". (And it can be very inefficient because you're doing that concatenation function on every node in the tree.)

The reason your `starts-with()` answer worked (sometimes) is that you got lucky: the parent node of the text node had other preceding siblings with their own text, so the grandparent node's text value started with something else. Also very inefficient...

If the text you're looking for will only be in one text node -- i.e. it will not be split up across multiple elements / comments / etc. -- then you can efficiently and accurately match only the element containing the text node, using **[edited]**:

```
//*[text()[contains(., "foo")]]
```

(similar to what @biziclop said).

If the text you're looking might be split up across multiple elements / comments / etc. -- then you can use this **[edited, twice]**:

```
//*[contains(., "foo") and not(*[contains(., "foo")])]
```

But that's fairly inefficient. The following is not guaranteed to work:

```
//*[contains(., "foo")][1]
```

It will give you **[edited, twice]** every element *that is a first child of its parent that (is an ancestor of one that) contains the text*. (Or an empty nodeset, if "foo" is not found.) I'm trusting @Alejandro on this one... I still have not internalized how to tell when [position() = x] applies to the most recent location step only. Regardless, this XPath expression is not guaranteed to give you the right result.

Comment: Thanks for that answer Lars. You really explained it all. Seems like i've got some alternatives on how i want it to work. Saving this one for future references. Thanks again.

Comment: @LarsH: First one meaning: *every element such that **first** text node child contains "foo"*. Second one: If I'm containing "foo", my parent always contains "foo". Last one meaning: *every first child containing "foo"*

Comment: @Alej: ah, good point. I'd forgotten that, about contains() taking the first node in its first argument nodeset... May have to edit. In fact, were all three of my sample XPaths wrong?? :-p

Comment: @Alej and @Henrik: updated my answer so it's hopefully correct now.

Comment: @LarsH: Now, first one is fine. Second one has the implicit casting problem: take the "any child element" node set out of the function call. About third: I rephrase the meaning: *from those children containing "foo", the first one*

Comment: @Alej: bah... you're right about the 2nd one. My brain is not working well. Re: 3rd: ok. Will edit. (We have rolling blackouts here so my connection is on and off.)

Answer (score 1):

> i'm trying to find out the parent-node
>   of the nodes content text.
>   [...] but it gives me all the parent
>   containing the text, i want only the
>   first parent.

The classic answer would be:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,$pText)]]
```

Meaning: *any element having at least one text node child containing `$pText` variable/param reference string value as part of its string value*

It was metioned the posible mixed content model. I doubt this is a real consideration, but any way, here is the answer:

```
//*[contains(.,$pText)][not(*[contains(.,$pText)])]
```

Meaning: *any element containing `$pText` as part of its string value, not having any child element with `$pText` as part of its string value*. In other words, innermost element containing `$pText` string value.